# Table of contents after renaming chapters in book document?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

After changing default chapter notation to Lecture, How do I get it to table of contents?
I'm getting only main chapter numbers. But I want my table of content to look like this,

Lecture 1

1.1 Introduction...........3

Lecture 2

2.2 GrahQL.................5

I have attached a M. W. E. below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Lecture}
\makeatother
\chapter{}
\section{Introduction}
\chapter{}
\section{GraphQL}
\end{document}
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% lecturetocprob.tex  SE 569160

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em}  % more space for number + Lecture
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Lecture }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Lecture}
\makeatother
\chapter{}

\section{Introduction}
\chapter{}
\section{GraphQL}

\appendix

\chapter{In appendix}

\end{document}
```

I have extended your MWE to include an Appendix just to check that that would be OK, even though you are probably not having any appendices.

[image]

Comment: Chose this as the answer, because this not only answers my question but also has given how to separate by chapters by small spacing in the toc.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch `\@chapter` so it issues `\chapternumberline` instead of `\numberline`: then we can define `\chapternumberline` to do what we prefer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}}
  {\patchcmd{\@chapter}}
  {\numberline}{\chapternumberline}{}{}
\newcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\chaptername\ #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{}
\section{Introduction}
\chapter{}
\section{GraphQL}

\end{document}
```

I made the patch working for the cases when `hyperref` is loaded or not.

Note that the correct command to redefine is `\chaptername` rather than `\@chapapp`.

[image]

Here's a picture when `hyperref` is used, showing that the entire entry is a link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would work:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{chapter}[0pt]{}
    {\bfseries\phantomsection\hyperlink{chapter.\thecontentslabel}{Lecture~\thecontentslabel}}{}
    {\hfill\bfseries\contentspage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Lecture}
\makeatother
\chapter{}
\section{Introduction}
\chapter{}
\section{GraphQL}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. kudos! but has a slight edge. hyperef in heading is gone now. Is there any fix to that?

Comment: @emil Thanks for pointing this out! I've edited my answer to support hyperlinks, check it ~